# How to use template variables in mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I let my users save email templates that are then used to send emails to customers. In these templates the users can add placeholder variables, for example %{sender.firstname}.

I need these values to be replaced with actual first name of the sender in this case.

Ruby got a feature that can take care of this (almost).

```
body = "Hello %{firstname}"
body % { :firstname => "James" }
```

The above code outputs:

```
Hello James
```

The problem is I want to use the prefix sender, like below but then I get an error. Seems like I have to use a single word symbol?

```
body = "Hello %{sender.firstname}"
body % { "sender.firstname" => "James" }
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):44
        1: from (irb):44:in `%'
KeyError (key{sender.firstname} not found)
```

How can I use the above method to look through a objects body, replace the variables and output the correct values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `#to_sym` on `"sender.firstname"` will fix it.

```rb
body % { "sender.firstname".to_sym => "James" }
# => "Hello James"
```

Comment: Sure did! What is this technique called?

Comment: Great! `String#to_sym` converts the string to a Symbol. Some methods like `String#%` require a Hash with Symbol keys instead of String. You can also do something like this: `{ "sender.firstname" => "James" }.symbolize_keys`. `Hash#symbolize_keys` converts all of the Hash keys to Symbol. There is also `Hash#with_indifferent_access` which makes it possible to access a Hash's keys with both String and Symbol. E.g. with `x = { a: 1 }.with_indifferent_access`, you can access `1` by both `x[:a]` and `x["a"]`. (Both `#symbolize_keys` and `#with_indifferent_access` are defined by Rails.)